# ¿Cómo incluir una variable en una rura storage de un controlador Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Estoy subiendo una imagen al servidor a través de un controlador, en el controlador se crea la ruta y luego se guarda en la base de datos... Funciona bien pero debo agregar un nombre de directorio dinámicamente a la ruta para diferenciarla de las demás, y lo intento con una variable, pero no me la toma la ruta.

Así funciona perfectamente:

```
$path = Storage::disk('public')->put('images/events/, $request->file('cover'));
```

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
$path = Storage::disk('public')->put('images/events/'. $code, $request->file('cover'));
```

Quiero lograr lo siguiente, si mi variable `$code` contiene `0504`

```
$path = Storage::disk('public')->put('images/events/0504', $request->file('cover'));
```

he intentado de varias maneras pero no lo logro...

```
$path = Storage::disk('public')->put('images/events/'". $code. "', $request->file('cover'));

$path = Storage::disk('public')->put('images/events/'. $code .'', $request->file('cover'));

$path = Storage::disk('public')->put("images/events/'. $code .'", $request->file('cover'));

$path = Storage::disk('public')->put('images/events/. $code .', $request->file('cover'));
```

Comment: la ruta `images/events/0504` existe???

Comment: no, pero se crea si no existe

Comment: en que momento la creas?? no te veo crearla :v

Comment: si no existe la crea, lo he probado sin la variable... CReo que es un proble con el contenido que llega al controlador, está llegando vacío... Estoy haciendo un dd($request->file('code')); hace rato funcionaba, algo pasó.

Comment: `dd($request->file('code'))` es `'code'` o `'cover'`?

Comment: Porque quieres crear un nombre de directorio nuevo para cada imagen? Porque no usas un nombre único a cada imagen y lo almacenas en un directorio?

Comment: Tengo ambos, code y cover... Porque necesito separar las imagenes en carpetas para una posterior lectura... Ya la otra aplicación está desarrollada para leerla así.

Comment: pero `'code'` es un archivo también?

Comment: Gracias cesar, además que no me estaba llegando el código tampoco tenía la línea de código para crear la carpta... a veces nos bloqueamos... code no es un archivo, copié y pegué y no lo cambié a get. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tu caso podrías usar `putFileAs` y crear el directorio de `$code`

```
use Illuminate\Http\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

if ($request->hasFile('cover')) {   //Se valida que el archivo esta cargado
    $directorio = 'images/events/'. $code;
    Storage::makeDirectory($directorio);
    // Especificar manualmente un nombre de archivo...
    $path = Storage::putFileAs($code, $request->file('cover'), 'nombreArchivo' o 'nombre.jpg', 'public');  //Si deseas que te regrese la ruta al guardar
    Storage::putFileAs($code, $request->file('cover'), 'nombreArchivo' o 'nombre.jpg', 'public');  //Sino necesitas que te regrese el path
}
```

Los parámetros de `putFileAs`:

1. Se especifica un nombre de directorio en este caso `$code`.
2. El archivo que se va a guardar `$request->file('cover')`.
3. Nombre que vas a colocar al archivo con la extensión o sin la extensión (el método tomara la extensión **MIME** del archivo `'cover'`).
4. Disco donde se va a guardar. *(opcional)*

Directorios: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#directories
Almacenar archivos: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#storing-files